# How to get every connected Ethernet interface in Swift on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

So i was able to find some related code:

```
for interface in SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll() as NSArray {
   if let type = SCNetworkInterfaceGetInterfaceType(interface as! SCNetworkInterface) {
       print("Connected interface of type \(type)")
   }
}
```

This allowed me to find all Ethernet interfaces, but what i need to do now is only list those Ethernet interfaces which are active (connected to a network, as observable in System Preferences).

How could i list all active **Ethernet** interfaces and their IP-Addresses in Swift on macOS?

Comment: You can get all information from `SCDynamicStore` in `SystemConfiguration` but it's not trivial, it's a lot of CoreFoundation stuff